# RXJS: Combining the results of multiple endpoint calls into a single array

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I have an RXJS Pipeline similar to this:

```js
const logs: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const url = 'http://some-url-here.com';

const pipeline = from(logs).pipe(
  switchMap(logId =>
    this.callEndpoint(url, logId).pipe(map(response => response.data)),
  ),
);

const res = await pipeline.toPromise();
console.log(res);



// The real function uses nestJS http service to call a url
callEndpoint(url: string, logId: number) {
  const result = Math.random() * 1000;
  console.log(`result in callEndpoint: ${result}`);
  return of({ data: result });
}
```

here is a sample output of the code:

```
result in callEndpoint: 586.773956063481
result in callEndpoint: 842.136341622411
result in callEndpoint: 964.0849490798163
result in callEndpoint: 598.7596176858414
598.7596176858414
```

The last number is the result of `res`.

How do I get the combined results of all the successful endpoint calls into a single array in `res`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toArray()` to collect all emission and emit them as one array after the source observable completes.

```
const pipeline = from(logs).pipe(
  switchMap(logId =>
    this.callEndpoint(url, logId).pipe(map(response => response.data)),
  ),
  toArray(),
);
```

However, I think you don't want to be using `switchMap` in this case because the source observable here is `from()` that will emit all items from `logs` immediatelly and  `switchMap` will keep subscribed only to the last one. So you might want to use `concatMap` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `forkJoin` if you want to send all requests at once or `concat` with `toArray` to send requests sequentially and collect the results in an array. You probably want to add error handling with `catchError` and return an observable that doesn't error in this case.

```ts
const getData = (logId) => this.callEndpoint(url, logId).pipe(
  map(response => response.data),
  catchError(error => of(null))
)
const requests = logs.map(logId => getData(logId));

// parallel requests
forkJoin(requests).subscribe(res => console.log(res));

// sequential requests
concat(...requests).pipe(toArray()).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

`res` will be an array that can contain `null` values if a request failed.
When the second request fails this might look like:

```
[586.773956063481, null, 964.0849490798163, 598.7596176858414]
```